# Enableing Facebook Users to Make posts

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I was able to set up my app so that a user can register with an email and password and was able to make a post but when I integrated the facebook login, I was not able to make any posts (writing to Firebase), I looked into permissions that might be necessary for those users but wasnt able to find anything. The following is my code for my posting to firebase

```
    @IBAction func handlePostButton(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let userProfile = UserService.currentUserProfile else { return }


    //Firebase code
    //Lets make a reference to the database
    let postref = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()    //This will assign this post a specific identifier that we can reference it by.
    //This is referencing the place where you write a post
    let postObject = [
        "author":[
            "uid": userProfile.uid,
            "photoURL": userProfile.photoURL.absoluteString,
            "username": userProfile.username
        ],
        "text": textView.text,
        "timestamp": [".sv": "timestamp"]           //This is actually getting the time from Firebase, this is a server value.
    ] as [String:Any]
    postref.setValue(postObject, withCompletionBlock: {Error, ref in
        if Error == nil {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }else {

            self.creatAlert(title: "Error", message: "Error making a Post!")
        }
    })

}
```

not sure what else I should put up.

Comment: make a post where exactly? on facebook? in your app?

Comment: @luschn make a post in my app, but the actual question is just writing to the firebase

Comment: ok, but right now all we know is "it does not work", you need to be more specific. did you debug it?

Comment: @luschn I tried but couldn’t get any resolution, I already have my rules set for auth users to write and read posts, I’m not sure if my Facebook user is considered “authenticated”

Comment: Could you confirm that `Facebook` is enabled (and you provided AppID and App Secret) in the "sign-in method" configuration for Authentication in Firebase?

Comment: @luschn I am not sure how to debug it, one thing that occurs is that when I sign up with a Facebook account, I see the user in my firebase for authenticated accounts. So I know that the set it is working and the user is getting authenticated